# How to throttle jobs with same parameters in a Jenkins multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline that uses scripted pipeline Jenkinsfiles.

In earlier versions (pre 2.0 I believe) versions of the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin, I was able to set my job properties to throttle concurrent builds that used identical parameters. In the 2.0 and later version of this plugin, that functionality looks to be lost. As far as I can tell, I can only throttle jobs based off of static categories that are defined globally. I need a large amount of jobs to run concurrently, but only if there are no jobs already running on that branch with the same parameters.

How can I throttle jobs with identical parameters in scripted multibranch pipelines? Do I have to use the locks functionality to create a mutex? Can the locks handle ~ 500 unique locks at a time? It looks like it lists these locks out in the global configuration, which will be very noisy.